# log4j.properties missing in Jenkins Build folder

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, log4j

We are doing Jenkins build for a dynamic web project. `log4j.properties` is located in `/src/main/resouces`.

When we do Jenkins build `log4j.properties` is not showing up in any folder of WAR.

But when we do maven local build, `log4j.properties` is in `WEB-INF\classes` folder.

I couldnt figure out why Jenkins WAR is not having `log4j.properties`.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Is there anything suspicious in Jenkins'  Console Output of the build?

Answer (score 0):

Added the following tag in Configuration tag of pom.xml.
After adding i did Jenkins build which has the log4j.properties as expected.

```
<systemPropertyVariables>                           <log4j.configuration>/src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```